# SSH jump host solution

Tags: ssh, proxy

I am researching the idea of implementing (using existing?) solutions of SSH jump hosts. There are two main use cases:

Organization wants to manage/limit/control the access to remote servers (certain people are allowed to login to certain servers). Organization wants to log commands issued by the user. As seamless as possible integration with organization infrastructure. One of the ideas was to use DNS to record designated remote, provide jump host's IP and capture connection.

The jump host based on LDAP will check if user is allowed to reach certain server and if so, will establish connection to remote and act like a proxy

Here are my questions:

1. Does the similar solution already exist ? (I couldn't find any)
2. What approach would you undertake to accomplish such use case(s) ? What do you think about utilizing DNS ?
3. How to ensure that user will not be aware of any jumps hosts on the way ? e.g. He would still be able to use X forwarding (`ssh someremote.host -X --other_option_that_should_work`).